# chef-client consumes 100% cpu usage on app server

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have hosted my app server on AWS and configured the chef to automate. Now chef-client consumes 100% CPU

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbAPe.png).

The server has 2 core and 4GiB memory.

There are no logs to check. After restarting the chef service it would be fine for a few mins and again CPU utilization is going high.

Please help to debug this.

Comment: First step is to check the logs and see what was printed last. Chef is, at heart, a programming language (specifically Ruby) so if you put `while true; end` in your recipe, chef-client will happily spinloop.

Comment: No logs in /var/log/chef/ directory. Even logs are not generated in chef workstation.

Comment: How are you running chef-client?

Comment: I have installed the chef using the knife bootstrap command.